# sorting mongodb through node.js

Tags: node-mongodb-native

I want to sort the result of the mongodb query I was doing some practice on it but I can't get the result as it was expected to do so here is the code

```
ro.find(function(err,objs){ 
    if(err) res.write('{"Find Error":"'+err.err+'"}');
    else {
        // Get our data from the collection store
        objs.sort(date).toArray(function(error, items)
                            {`
            if(error)res.write('{"Find Error":"'+error.err+'"}');
            else{
               res.write(JSON.stringify(items));
               es.end();
            }
        });
    }
});//
```

Comment: I don't see where the `date` variable is declared. Maybe you wanted to do `objs.sort('date')`. See [documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find)

Comment: OBJ is the parameter to the function see first line

Comment: I saw where `objs` is declared, I don't see where `date` is declared.

Comment: Check if this answer helps regarding sorting:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35377962/5333841

Answer (score 2):

You can already sort in query as follow,

```
ro.find().sort({date : 1}).exec( function(err, result){
if(err)
res.write('{"Find Error":"'+error.err+'"}');
else{
      res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
      res.end();
    }
});
```

if you want to order ascending , you have to set

date : 1

but you need descending ,need to change

date : -1

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You might look for MongoDB's [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) method.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847766/how-to-sort-a-collection-by-date-in-mongodb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559735/how-sort-results-in-a-nodejs-mongodb-search-but-by-calling-a-dynamic-method) previous questions might contain the solution to your problem.
In this way, you have to move the callback that handles the data from the `find` method to the `sort`.